# How to make query that will fetch multiple posts from different owners?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a feed of posts and want to fetch posts from both the current user and the users that the current user follows. I have fetched the current user's posts (to show on their profile) and, separately, I have fetched posts from the user's following list (to show on the feed). I want to pull the user's ID into that fetchfollowingposts() function so that I can see both my following list's post and my posts. Identical to Instagram how I can post and see my posts in my feed along with the people I follow posts.

So I have a collection of posts, each post has a field titled `uid`. I want to fetch my following list with `uid` in it and my own posts to get single result.

some things I've tried:

- in feedservice -> fetchfollowingposts() I have tried to using firebase's "in" query like this:

```
COLLECTION_POSTS.where("uid", "in", [userId, uid])
```

- I've also tried using contains/in array but those didn't work for me either.. Thank you in advance!

**FeedService**

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct FeedService {
    
    func uploadPost(caption: String, image: UIImage?, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        ImageUploader.uploadImage(image: image, type: .post) { imageUrl in
            let data = ["uid": uid,
                        "caption": caption,
                        "likes": 0,
                        "imageUrl": imageUrl,
                        "timestamp": Timestamp(date: Date())] as [String: Any]
            
            COLLECTION_POSTS.document()
                .setData(data) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("DEBUG: Failed to upload post with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    }
                }
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    
    
    func fetchCurrentUsersPosts(forUid uid: String, completion: @escaping([Post]) -> Void) {
        COLLECTION_POSTS
            .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
            .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
                let posts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
                completion(posts.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp.dateValue() > $1.timestamp.dateValue()
                }))
            }
    }
    
    func fetchFollowingPosts(forUid uid: String, completion: @escaping([Post]) -> Void) {
        var posts = [Post]()
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        COLLECTION_FOLLOWING.document(currentUid).collection("user-following")
            .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
                
                documents.forEach { doc in
                    let followingIds = doc.documentID
                    
                    COLLECTION_POSTS.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: followingIds)

                        .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
                            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
                            let post = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
                            posts.append(contentsOf: post)
                            
                            completion(posts.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp.dateValue() > $1.timestamp.dateValue()
                            }))
                        }
                }
            }
    }
```

**FeedViewModel**

```
import SwiftUI

class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var followingPosts = [Post]()
    let service = FeedService()
    let userService = UserService()
    
    init() {
        fetchFollowingPosts()
    }
    
    func fetchFollowingPosts() {
        
        guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }
        
        service.fetchFollowingPosts(forUid: currentUid) { posts in
            self.followingPosts = posts
            
            for i in 0 ..< posts.count {
                let uid = posts[i].uid
                
                self.userService.fetchUser(withUid: uid) { user in
                    self.followingPosts[i].user = user
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no such a thing like current `uid`. I doubt someone will understand what you want to achieve. You can assign different types of fields, but I doubt it's a good practice. Better would be to create new collection for different documents.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain it well. on instagram I am able to make a post and see it in the same feed where I see all the user's I follow posts. I have created a function to pull the current user's posts and I have created a separate function to pull that person's following list's posts. I want to combine them so I can see both my following posts & my own posts in the same feed. both user id's are found under the same collection - posts.

Comment: Edit your question and there explain it better.

Comment: it's edited now to reflect that

Comment: I edited your posts and changed the title. Try to name your variables better. In my opinion, it would be better if you change field name in your posts from `uid` to `ownerId`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Mises asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo i did edit it based on Mises suggestions? Not sure what else to change about it